# Testing SMTP via Telnet, "help" returns "500 unrecognized command"

Tags: windows, putty, smtp

When using PuTTY in Windows (I specify a mail server, Telnet protocol, and port 25), the "help" command returns "500 unrecognized command". This is strange since I expected to get some actual help.

Also, what commands can I use in PuTTY in this manner to test if an outgoing SMTP server is functioning correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Your mail server is telling you it has no help command. Thats what its designed to do

I've based my answer off the absolutely brilliant CC [licensed guide off flurdy.com](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/). His version is clearer - so check that out (he has a whole section for [troubleshooting](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/#test)), and the whole guide is worth reading and understanding - he covers EVERYTHING you will need. I've made a few changes, such as assuming you're already telnetted in, and I've commented out where he's mentioned the expected output for more clarity, since I don't have the benefit of coloured text. The rest of this answer is primarily for search-ability and redundancy. Use the non commented lines one line at a time, don't copy and paste them since this is basically telling the mail server what it wants to hear, as if you were a mail client.

```
# Open the hand shake with ehlo and the server name you are connecting from... 
# This time it has to be the name of your server 
EHLO mail.example.org 
# The mail server will then dump out some details about its capabilities, e.g. 
#>250-mail.flurdy.net 
#>250-PIPELINING 
#>.... 
#>.... #
 then say who is the sender of this email, which is a local user 
MAIL FROM: <xandros@example.org> 
> 250 Ok 
# then say who the mail is for which is an external address e.g. gmail etc. 
RCPT TO: <you@example.com> 
> 250 Ok 
# then enter the keyword data 
data 
 > 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF></LF></CR></LF></CR> 
# enter message body and end with a line with only a full stop. 
 blah blah blah 
 more blah 
 . 
 #> 250 Ok; queued as QWKJDKASAS 
 # end the connection with 
 quit 
 > 221 BYE
```

once thats done, check if you've received the message. If not, check your logs for error messages - this should be `/var/log/mail.log`.